# Wandel and Wechsel

Tags: meaning, translation, difference

I saw somewhere the following quote:

> Wandel und Wechsel liebt, wer lebt.

What is the best way to translate this quote into English? My attempt:

> Who lives, likes change and abrupt change.

Comment: Using the same noun for both translations is grating, even with a qualifier. Since *Wandel* is gradual and *Wechsel* instantaneous, you want terms like "transitions and reverses" instead.

Answer (score 4):

Evolution and revolution are loved by those, who live.

Comment: Very nice that you pick the formal "poetic" feature (anaphora) and find a translation which also contains a formal poetic feature (rhyme)! Would give +5 for that, if it was possible.

Comment: Maybe Janka's "loves who lives" would fit nicely here too

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Vielleicht entscheidet sich Janka ja noch, was sie als Kommentar gepostet hat in eine Antwort umzuwandeln.

Answer (score 3):

> - Evolution and revolution loves who lives.
> - Evolution and revolution loves he who lives.
> - Evolution and revolution love they who live.

Personally, I find the prosody with a personal pronoun better.

Comment: _... love they who live_...

Comment: I am not sure, but I think, using plural is a standard in English when talking about a person whose gender is unknown. It is even used when there is definitely only one person. But I don't know if the use is limited to the academic domain.

Comment: There are many idioms with _he who_. https://www.dict.cc/?s=he+who